# Generate android apk with cache file

Tags: android, cordova, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making an android webview application,there are a lot of files such as js/css/images must be downloaded from CDN to the app, because the network is not stable in our region and the size of the cached files is much bigger than the app itself, is there some way to build the apk file with the cache files stored automatically when the app runs at first few times.

Answer (score 0):

Put your files and folders to assets. you'll find it in your project directory. When your application runs copy all assets contents to your SD card. then run your app :)

If you need any help about how to copy assets content to SD card let me know.

Comment: Sorry I never made an app before.Could you please tell me more details how to do this thing,thank you!

Comment: I've added another answer. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy Assets contents to SD card**

Bellow code will copy all the contents of specified folder of your assets to your specified location of your SD card

CopyAssetContents.java
    public class CopyAssetContents {

```
    public static boolean copyAssetFolder(AssetManager assetManager,String fromAssetPath, String toPath) {
        try {
            String[] files = assetManager.list(fromAssetPath);
            new File(toPath).mkdirs();
            boolean res = true;
            for (String file : files)
                if (file.contains("."))
                    res &= copyAsset(assetManager, 
                            fromAssetPath + "/" + file,
                            toPath + "/" + file);
                else 
                    res &= copyAssetFolder(assetManager, 
                            fromAssetPath + "/" + file,
                            toPath + "/" + file);
            return res;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static boolean copyAsset(AssetManager assetManager,
            String fromAssetPath, String toPath) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open(fromAssetPath);
          new File(toPath).createNewFile();
          out = new FileOutputStream(toPath);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
          return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
          out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

For example you have all your contents in a folder named "CONTENTS" inside of your assets.and want to copy all of its content to root of your SD card.
call bellow method.

```
CopyAssetContents.copyAssetFolder(getAssets(), "CONTENTS", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```